# How to preserve formatting in long text fields in LWC components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have an issue where while vewing a long text fields data in a standard layout the spacing between para's are preserved. Looks neat. However, when I am trying to read and display the same data in an LWC component it does not preserve the formatting and looks crappy.

Standard View

[image: Standard view]

LWC component

[image: Then when im displaying using the lwc component]

How I preserve the formatting?

Here is my code snippet

```
<tr class="tr">
              <td class="data">Services Requested :</td>
              <template if:true={hasData}>
                <td class="td">{erateBasicInfo.Services_Requested__c}</td>
              </template>
              <template if:false={hasData}> <td class="td"></td></template>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you have in field? just new lines or also HTML tags? have you tried using [`lightning-formatted-rich-text`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation) or [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag

Comment: I just have text in the field. No HTML tags. Let me try  lightning-formatted-rich-text

Comment: @Raul Thanks! The <pre> tag worked. Please post as answer ill select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the preformatted tags either use [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag.

Comment: lightning-formatted-rich-text did not work, but <pre> tag did it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

just use `lightning-formatted-text` instead of `lightning-formatted-rich-text`